# Dynamically change ID of a rails checkbox, and grab each one with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble creating individual id's when looping through rails variables.  I wan't each "product" to have its own ID on the "switch" so I can activate the switch once a element from the dropdown is chosen.

My form:

```
        = form_tag orders_path, id: 'payment-form' do
      - @foo.products.each do |product|
        %li.bullet-item 
          .product.panel
            .small-12
              %h4
                = content_tag_for :li, product, :value => product.id do
                  .row
                    .small-2.columns.switch
                      %input#switchName{:type => "checkbox"}/
                      %label{:for => "switchName"}
                    .small-7.columns
                      = hidden_field_tag("order_products[][product_id]", product.id)
                      = product.name
                      %br
                      .subheader= number_to_currency(product.cost_in_cents.to_f/100)

                    .small-3.columns
                      = select_tag("order_products[][quanity]", options_for_select([0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]), "data-cost-per-unit" => product.cost_in_cents, id: product.name, class: 'thing')
```

my jQuery

```
:javascript
  $('.thing').change(function() {
    $('#switchName').click();
  });
```

This will click the first switch, but the problem is that both switches are named 'switchName'.  When a quantity is chosen, I want it to click that switch it's associated with.

As you see here, If I have two products rendered they both have the same ID.

[image: whats rendered]

How can I get this to click different switches for different products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 - @foo.products.each_with_index do |product, index|
```

Then use the index to set input's id to "switchName#{index}"

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick.  I have another question for you if you have the time.  Now that I have the length, and know how many switches there are.  Would I save them into a variable, then loop through them with a `.each` to individually select what needs to be selected?

Comment: If you are taking about javascript, you can select an specific item with `$("#switchName"+index)` or select them all `#(".switch input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event) { /* event.target has the clicked item */ } )`

Comment: Getting closer, thanks.  Now when when I try `$("#switchName"+index)` i'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined `

Comment: I was assuming you know which item you are looking for,`index` was just a placeholder for the identifier of the item you are selecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it his way, you can use your own custom bindings. For example:

```
%input#switchName{:type => "checkbox", :prodid => product.id}
```

and then use

```
$('#switchname').on('change',function() {
    var product_id = $(this).attr("prodid");
    // do some more of your magic here
});
```